Does Azure Devops charges for the storage of build Files?
I have the following scenario: I Build my application on Azure Devops Services and then publish the build files to Azure Devops Services Pipeline using the task "Publish Pipeline Artifacts". What I would like to know is if Microsoft charges for these files that are the product of the build process. I am not using the artifact section of Azure Devops Services ( which I know that there are a limit od 2GB for free) But I could not find the information related do the build files.
OBS: The artifact section ( which gives the 2GB free ) is empty, even though I`ve triggered multiple build pipelines.
Can anyone confirm if keeping those build files are already included on the service ( or if it`s consume based )?
I would like not to pay for this build files storage. Could someone explain if this is really possible?

According to this Q&A :

Q: Which artifacts contribute to my total billed storage?
A: You will be charged for all package types (npm, NuGet, Python, Maven, Cargo, and Universal Packages), including packages stored from upstream sources. However, there will be no charges for Pipeline Artifacts and Pipeline Caching

So, the Pipeline Artifacts are free to use. You don't need to warry about the cost of it.
However, it’s important to note that these pipeline artifacts are not intended for long-term storage as they are automatically deleted after a certain period depending on the retention policies. You can refer the retention policies document for more details.

Ohh I see, thank you!

You are welcome. You can also monitor Artifacts storage consumption following the steps here


Does Azure Devops charges for the storage of build Files?

According to the Azure DevOps billing overview, the only thing related to the Azure Pipelines service that gets charged is parallel jobs, i.e. the possibility of using multiple build agents at the same time.
There is no mention of storage costs except for Azure Artifacts.
The free tier of Azure DevOps includes the following aspects:

First five users free (Basic license)
Azure Pipelines

One Microsoft-hosted CI/CD (one concurrent job, up to 30 hours per month)
One self-hosted CI/CD concurrent job


Azure Boards: Work item tracking and boards
Azure Repos: Unlimited private Git repos
Azure Artifacts: Two GiB free per organization

See also Pricing for Azure DevOps.
